# How can i call a function via trigger in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

(I am using Oracle Database XE 18c and SQL Developer)

We have a table named "courses" (cid: varchar2, cname: varchar2, credit: integer, did: integer) and we have a table named "course_history" with same attributes.

When an update is made on credit attribute at the courses table, a trigger should call a function, and the function should insert the old attribute values to "course_history".

Trigger and function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fun RETURN VOID IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO course_history
    VALUES(:OLD.cid, :OLD.cname, :OLD.credit, :OLD.did);
END;



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
AFTER UPDATE OF CREDIT ON COURSE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- ???
END;
```

How can i call a function inside a trigger? Also, is it possible that a function to return void in PLSQL?

Thank you.

Comment: [*is it possible that a function to return void in PLSQL*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-391C58FD-16AF-486C-AF28-173E309CDBA5). And why do you need a function to insert some records if you can just write the same insert within a trigger? Even for function: you can use procedure for this task. Did you try to write an actual code and test it by yourself?

Comment: This is not a good use of a function.  The proper use of a function is to simply return a value to the caller.  Look at all of the functions in the SQL Language Reference.  None of them modifies stored data.  Just code the actions of your imagined function directly into the trigger.  Cont ..

Comment: ... cont...  iThat said, your table structure looks suspicious Why two tables with _identical_ structure?  I'd think the history table should have some additional columns to show effective date or some such.  If I took a course and earned 5 credits, I'd hate to have that reduced to 3 credits a few years from now when the course is re-structured.

Comment: Your model also lacks something that can identify the history: SQL tables have no row order, so there should be some additional column to identify the time/event/order when the change was made.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Actually it was just a question in lab experiment that i couldn't solve. I could simply use a procedure or just use a trigger to do the job as you said but it says, using a function and a trigger is mandatory for the question. And i am aware that log table should have some additional information like date and time. But as i said, it's just a simple lab quesiton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use a function.  A function is used to read data and return a value.  Use a procedure.  Procedures are used to modify data.
2. Your procedure will need to take parameters.  It won't have access to the `:new` pseudorecord.

It sounds like you want something like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure insert_history( 
  p_cid in course.cid%type,
  p_cname in course.cname%type,
  p_credit in course.credit%type,
  p_did in course.did%type
)
as
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO course_history( cid, cname, credit, did )
    VALUES(p_cid, p_cname, p_credit, p_did);
END;



CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig
AFTER UPDATE OF CREDIT ON COURSE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   insert_history( :new.cid, :new.cname, :new.credit, :new.did );
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually it was a lab experiment question and using a function and a trigger was mandatory. I think it is just a bad-written question.